# scrollbar stylesheet

Tags: css

I have following stylesheet and It changes colors of scrollbars of web browser.
but the problem is it changes all the scroll bar including browser's main scrollbar.

I'd like to apply this only to overflowed area. thanks

for instance,

```
<div style="overflow: scroll">this area</div>
```

---

```
/* Turn on a 13x13 scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}

/* Turn on single button up on top, and down on bottom */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment {
    display: block;
}

/* Turn off the down area up on top, and up area on bottom */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start:increment,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:decrement {
    display: none;
}

/* Place The scroll down button at the bottom */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}

/* Place The scroll up button at the up */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
    background-color: purple;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track:vertical {
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px dashed pink;
}

/* Top area above thumb and below up button */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:start {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

/* Bottom area below thumb and down button */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:end {
    border: 1px dashed pink;
}

/* Track below and above */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-color: green;
}

/* The thumb itself */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

/* Corner */
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner:vertical {
    background-color: black;
}

/* Resizer */
::-webkit-scrollbar-resizer:vertical {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Your css is targeting any scrollbar, perhaps set it to target the specific divs which have their own scroll bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/Bghcr/1/

- Give the element(s) to which the style is to be applied a class name
- Use the class name to narrow the scope of the scrollbar selectors

### HTML

```
<div class="custom-scroll">this area</div>​
```

### CSS

```
.custom-scroll {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}

.custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
}

.custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}

/* ETC */
```

### Other Notes

- `<div class="overflow: scroll">` is invalid--perhaps you meant `<div style="overflow:scroll">`?
- CSS selector reference - http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/